# Remap altgr key to AC10 in XKB

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'd like to remap the altgr key to AC10 key.
So far, I edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` as follows:

```
// key <AC10> { [ semicolon,  colon   ] };
   key <AC10> { [ Alt_R ]}
```

After

```
$ cd /var/lib/xkb; sudo rm *
$ setxkbmap us
Error loading new keyboard description
```

Is there a way to achieve this mapping? I'd like to use `AC10` as `Alt_R`. `semicolon` and `colon` will be mapped on some other keys.

I achieved this behavior in `xmodmap`

`keycode 47 = ISO_Level3_Shift`

And wonder if it's possible in `xkb` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing error when loading your modified file is due to the missing semicolon at the end of the line; fix it and it will load.

But if you change `AC10` key to send `Alt_R`, then it will send just an `Alt` modifier; if you want `AltGr`, that is, a key to access 3rd level symbols, then you have to send `ISO_Level3_Shift`:

```
key <AC10> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
```