# Swapping keys AltGr and Space in Kali - Firefox is not affected

Tags: kali-linux, xkb

After trying several <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key remapping ideas, changing `xkb` looks most promising. I read and used these ideas related to `xkb`:
[Remap altgr key to AC10 in XKB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68178/remap-altgr-key-to-ac10-in-xkb)
[How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys#681740)

From the first glance my corrections seem to work in text editor and in the terminal(<kbd>Space</kbd> symbol is printed on <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key press). However, in Firefox it does not work. Looking more closely, I have noticed that in all the three applications key combinations with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> also work (as if no remapping was done), except that in the terminal and in text editor the combination additionally prints the space character. E.g., in the terminal and in FireFox the combination <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> opens the *File* menu and in the terminal also a space character is printed.

My <kbd>Space</kbd> is broken and I don't use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. I just want to completely swap their functionality. What am I missing? (I use Kali Linux.)

This is what I did:
`1.` Opened `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`
`2.` Changed the commented line with the one below:

```
 // key <SPCE> {    [    space      ]   };
 key <SPCE> {   [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };
```

`3.` Added these lines:

```
// Additionally added
key <RALT> {    [    32     ]   };
```

`4.` Saved the `pc` file.
`5.` Cleared the `xkb` cache running `rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*`
`6.` Restarted

---

Additional information (after the alterations listed above).

Full current `pc` file:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "pc105" {

    key <ESC>  {    [ Escape        ]   };

    // The extra key on many European keyboards:
    key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };

    // The following keys are common to all layouts.
    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,    bar ]   };
    // key <SPCE> { [    space      ]   };
    key <SPCE> {    [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };

    include "srvr_ctrl(fkey2vt)"
    include "pc(editing)"
    include "keypad(x11)"

    key <BKSP> {    [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };

    key  <TAB> {    [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };
    key <RTRN> {    [ Return        ]   };

    key <CAPS> {    [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
    key <NMLK> {    [ Num_Lock      ]   };

    key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
    key <LCTL> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
    key <LWIN> {    [ Super_L       ]   };

    key <RTSH> {    [ Shift_R       ]   };
    key <RCTL> {    [ Control_R     ]   };
    key <RWIN> {    [ Super_R       ]   };
    key <MENU> {    [ Menu          ]   };

    // Beginning of modifier mappings.
    modifier_map Shift  { Shift_L, Shift_R };
    modifier_map Lock   { Caps_Lock };
    modifier_map Control{ Control_L, Control_R };
    modifier_map Mod2   { Num_Lock };
    modifier_map Mod4   { Super_L, Super_R };

    // Fake keys for virtual<->real modifiers mapping:
    key <LVL3> {    [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };
    key <MDSW> {    [ Mode_switch       ]   };
    modifier_map Mod5   { <LVL3>, <MDSW> };

    key <ALT>  {    [ NoSymbol, Alt_L   ]   };
    include "altwin(meta_alt)"

    key <META> {    [ NoSymbol, Meta_L  ]   };
    modifier_map Mod1   { <META> };

    key <SUPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Super_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <SUPR> };

    key <HYPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Hyper_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <HYPR> };
    // End of modifier mappings.

    key <OUTP> { [ XF86Display ] };
    key <KITG> { [ XF86KbdLightOnOff ] };
    key <KIDN> { [ XF86KbdBrightnessDown ] };
    key <KIUP> { [ XF86KbdBrightnessUp ] };

    // Additionally added
    key <RALT> {    [    32     ]   };

};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "editing" {
    key <PRSC> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Print, Sys_Req ]
    };
    key <SCLK> {    [  Scroll_Lock      ]   };
    key <PAUS> {
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Pause, Break ]
    };
    key  <INS> {    [  Insert       ]   };
    key <HOME> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Prior        ]   };
    key <DELE> {    [  Delete       ]   };
    key  <END> {    [  End          ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Next         ]   };

    key   <UP> {    [  Up           ]   };
    key <LEFT> {    [  Left         ]   };
    key <DOWN> {    [  Down         ]   };
    key <RGHT> {    [  Right        ]   };
};
```

`setxkbmap -print`:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

`xev` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd> press and release):

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 1249191, (168,-8), root:(797,298),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 1249261, (168,-8), root:(797,298),
    state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As my keyboard's <kbd>Space</kbd> key is broken, I cannot show its `xev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually made it work even with `xkeymap`, I leave it here as a different answer because the method is strictly different from my previous solution.

Maybe you've missed some occurrence of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> usage.

Trying to mimic your setup, I've exported the current configuration file with the command `xkbcomp $DISPLAY current.xkb` and edited it by removing all `ISO_Level3_Shift`, `LVL3` and `Mod5` occurrences.

Precisely, what I've deleted is:

```
interpret ISO_Level3_Shift+AnyOf(all) {
    virtualModifier= LevelThree;
    useModMapMods=level1;
    action= SetMods(modifiers=LevelThree,clearLocks);
};
```

```
interpret ISO_Level3_Shift+AnyOfOrNone(all) {
    action= SetMods(modifiers=LevelThree,clearLocks);
};
```

```
key <LVL3> {
    type= "ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
};
```

```
key <RALT> {
    type= "ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
};
```

```
modifier_map Mod5 { <LVL3> };
```

Then I've inserted:

```
key <LVL3> {[space]};
key <RALT> {[space]};
```

This edited configuration can be tested by loading it with

```
xkbcomp new_conf.xkb $DISPLAY
```

Comment: As `xev`'s output show, although the keysym was remapped successfully, the AltGr key retains its modifier property, possibly confusing some applications. This solution removes the modifier property. Very nice, +1.

Comment: I have not tested this answer myself, as your other answer worked brilliantly. However, I will accept this one as correct, because my original question was about `xkb`.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any reference that proves that what you've proposed should not work on Firefox, while it seems that Chromium (and therefore Chrome) does not relies on xkeymaps: it is a [developing choice](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=394552#c18) that better integrates the program in ChromeOS. Some system remapping can therefore be not supported.

A fix that worked for me is to remap keycodes at kernel level.
To achieve this, I've collected scan-codes (the hardware ID of the key) and key-codes (the symbol in which they are mapped) for both space and altGr:

```bsh
# to collect scan-codes
sudo showkey -s
# space press: 0x39
# altGr press: 0xe0 0x38

# to collect key-codes
sudo showkey
# space press: 57
# altGr press: 100
```

As far as I understood, you'd like to remap the altGr to space because your spacebar is broken, therefore:

```bsh
sudo setkeycodes e038 57
```

should do the trick.

---

In order to make this permanent under Kali Linux, you have to edit the default xinit file, `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc`, by coping it to `~/.xinitrc` and inserting `sudo setkeycodes e038 57` before the if statement that contains `exec xfce4-session`; on Kali 20.04 default file, this if statement is on line 86.

Note that this requires to [enable sudo without password](https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/enable-sudo-without-password-in-ubuntudebian/)), but as far as I can recall, this is already the default option in Kali.

Comment: @Maik93 - the suggestion worked, but I'm struggling with the last thing. It seems that my system does not have `~/.xinitrc`. `cat ~/.xinitrc` returns `No such file or directory`. `Find` found 2 files `xinitrc`, but neither contained `exec gnome-session`.

Comment: Sorry, I saw Kali only when it was called Backtrack: at that time its Desktop Environment was Gnome. I see now that Kali is currently based on Xfce4, therefore you should copy its default configurations with `cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc` and edit the file generated in your home directory. In there, I can find `exec xfce4-session` (on line 102, inside an if test). I suggest you to insert the line above before that if statement, e.g. on line 86.

Comment: I strongly suggest updating your answer with the info from the last comment. I inserted the command in the `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` and now the remap works after reboot.

Comment: Even though I have accepted the other answer as correct, I actually went for this option on my machine. So I want to grant this one the bounty.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to hear that this worked well for you. I've update my answer, but please note that any edits on the system file `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` may be overwritten by `xfce4` updates. It should be better to copy that file in `~/.xinitrc` (note the dot in the destination file name).